# Splitting filename - weird behavior

Tags: string, powershell, split

I'm trying to split a filename like `XXX_YYYY-YYYY_fff.xxx`

If I'm using

```
'XXX_YYYY-UUUU_fff.xxx' -split '[-_`.]'
```

everything is working fine, showing:

```
XXX
YYYY
UUUU
fff
xxx
```

But when I'm using

```
'XXX_YYYY-UUUU_fff.xxx' -split '[_-`.]'
```

it does not split on dashes:

```
XXX
YYYY-UUUU
fff
xxx
```

Can anybody explain why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-` specifies a range of characters in a regular expression. To get what you want, "escape" the `-` with `\`; e.g.:

```
C:\> 'XXX_YYYY-UUUU_fff.xxx' -split '[_\-.]'
XXX
YYYY
UUUU
fff
xxx
```

i.e., split the string using any of the following characters: `_`, `-`, or `.`.

You can also tell the regular expression parser that the `-` is a literal character in the set by placing it at the beginning of the set just after the `[` or at the end of the set by placing it just before the `]`, as in:

```
[-_.]
```

or

```
[_.-]
```

Comment: Or move the `-` so it is the first character inside the square brackets.

Comment: Correct; placing `-` as the first character in the set after `[` or as the last character before the `]` causes the regex parser not to interpret it as a range specifier.

Comment: That's right - this is why it worked in one case and did not work in another